# ¿Cómo puedo verificar la conexión a Internet en una aplicación Ionic incluso cuando está cerrada en segundo plano?

Tags: ionic, capacitor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Ionic y me gustaría implementar una funcionalidad que permita verificar la conexión a Internet incluso cuando la aplicación está cerrada en segundo plano. Quisiera saber si hay alguna estrategia o plugin recomendado para lograr esto.

En mi aplicación, necesito la capacidad de saber si la conexión a Internet está disponible o no, y preferiblemente también cuando la aplicación está cerrada. ¿Alguien ha enfrentado este desafío antes o tiene alguna sugerencia sobre cómo abordarlo de manera efectiva?

Aprecio cualquier consejo o experiencia que puedan compartir. ¡Gracias de antemano!